# Audio storage best practice

Tags: database, audio, local-storage

I am developing some desktop software. I need a some storage for audio files. There are a large amount of audio files.

I have no experience with storing audio data. What is the best practice for this case?
Where can I read something about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft .Net Technologies, here are a couple of articles that can get you started.

1. [Storing Uploaded Files in a Database or in the File System with
   ASP.NET 2.0.](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20)
2. [Building a Provider Based File Storage System
   Using .NET.](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/556/building-a-provider-based-file-storage-system-using-net)

Note:

- Both articles are "dated" (i.e. few years old, but you may find the
  design ideas and interfaces useful for designing your application.
- 1st Article discusses Pros and Cons of storing files inside a
  Database Vs on File System. Depending on your needs and use case, you
  may choose 1 or the other.

Hope this helps get started.